# Registering for Email and Other Push Events on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

Using the Iphone NSNotificationCenter class is it possible to register for incoming email push notifications or indeed for any push notifications from say FB ?  I understand how the class works but I want to be able to receive a notification from say the mail client when a new email arrives and then process that in my app.

I am only looking to register this as an observer - I dont need to be sending any notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSNotificationCenter` is not for those kind of notifications. You can't detect other pushnotification other then the ones for your app.